# Typeof evaluates differently depending on parentheses

Tags: javascript, typeof

I have the following code example :

```
Application.Polyfills.prototype.prettifyCode = function(enable, js_lib, css_lib) {
    return Modernizr.load([{
        test : enable,
        yep : [ css_lib, js_lib ],
        complete: function() {
            return window.prettyPrint && prettyPrint();
        }
    }]);
};
```

If I do a `console.log(typeof this.prettifyCode)`, in which `this` refers to the `Application.Polyfills`, I get `function`, but if I do `console.log(typeof this.prettifyCode())` I get `undefined`. Can someone tell me why do I get that and how can I fix it so I get the same result in both cases, because most of the times the functions require arguments so I need to use parentheses ?

To be more specific, I have a method :

```
Application.Polyfills.prototype.callPolyfills = function(array) {
    for (var i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        console.log(typeof array[i]);
        (typeof array[i] === "function") ? array[i].apply(this, [ this ]) : console.log('Index [' + i + ']: Invalid [ Function Required ]') ;
    };
};
```

The above method is used to call all my functions that are placed inside an array, something like the following :

```
this.callPolyfills([
        self.polyfillize([
            {
                test : [Modernizr.localstorage, Modernizr.sessionstorage],
                polyfill : [self.polyfills_url.storage_polyfill_url]
            },
            {
                test : [Modernizr.json],
                polyfill : [self.polyfills_url.json_polyfill_url]
            }
        ]),
        self.prettifyCode(self.prettify, self.libraries_url.google_code_prettyfier.css, self.libraries_url.google_code_prettyfier.js),
        self.consoleAvoidError()
    ]);
```

Making abstraction of all the variables in there that are unknown, I would like to see if what I call in that array is actually a function, as I'm already trying to check now in the `callPolyfills` method. But it fails because it returns `undefined` each time even though it's a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe instead of calling explicitly your polyfills inside of callPolyfills, you could change your approach? Like this:

```
this.callPolyfills([
    [self.polyfillize, [
        {
            test : [Modernizr.localstorage, Modernizr.sessionstorage],
            polyfill : [self.polyfills_url.storage_polyfill_url]
        },
        {
            test : [Modernizr.json],
            polyfill : [self.polyfills_url.json_polyfill_url]
        }
    ]],
    [self.prettifyCodeself.prettify, self.libraries_url.google_code_prettyfier.css, self.libraries_url.google_code_prettyfier.js],
    self.consoleAvoidError
]);
```

So then you would check like this:

```
Application.Polyfills.prototype.callPolyfills = function(array) {
    for (var i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (typeof array[i] == "function") {
            // call with no arguments
            array[i].apply(this);
        }
        else if (typeof array[i].shift() == "function") {
            // call with arguments
            array[i].apply(this, array[i]);
        }
        else {
            // Invalid [ Function Required ]') ;
        }
    };
};
```

Comment: Shouldn't this line `[self.prettifyCodeself.prettify, self.libraries_url.google_code_prettyfier.css, self.libraries_url.google_code_prettyfier.js]` be like `[self.prettifyCode [ self.prettify, self.libraries_url.google_code_prettyfier.css, self.libraries_url.google_code_prettyfier.js]]` ?

Comment: `else if (typeof array[i].shift() == "function") {` is actually removing the element, leaving you unable to call it. Also note that the array is being iterated in reverse, so you'd need to use `pop()` instead.

Comment: @Roland: if you change the line you suggested as you mentioned, and the `else if` condition and block to `else if (array[i] instanceof Array) { array[i][0].apply(this, array[i][1]); }` (https://gist.github.com/4468240) you should be good-to-go.

Answer (score 4):

`typeof this.prettifyCode()` is checking the type of the value returned by `this.prettifyCode()`; which is `undefined`.

`typeof this.prettifyCode` however, is checking what the type of the `prettifyCode` member on `this` is; which is a `function`

You shouldn't *want* these to be the same. The only way they *could* be the same is if `this.prettifyCode` returned a function, but the fact that both `typeof this.prettifyCode()` and `typeof this.prettifyCode` would be `function` is meaningless.

Comment: I don't necessary want them to be the same, just that it would make sense for the case with parentheses to evaluate as a function

Comment: It actually makes sense :) .... but then how do I check if the case with parentheses is a function ?

Comment: `typeof this.prettifyCode === "function"` will show that `this.prettifyCode` is callable with the `()` (i.e. as a function). All `typeof this.prettyifyCode() === "undefined"` is showing is that the function *returns* `undefined`.

Comment: See my edits, maybe you'll understand what I'm trying to achieve :)

Answer (score 1):

<sup>Adding this as a new answer as the two answers aren't realling related at all</sup>

---

You're function `callPolyfills` is spot on; it's what you're passing to `callPolyfills` that is the problem (you're passing an array of the *results* of the functions you wan't to call, not the functions themselves).

```
function foo() {
    return "hi";
};

var bar = foo; // stores a reference to the function foo in `bar`, but doesn't call foo.
var baz = foo(); // calls foo and stores the result of the function ("hi") in baz.
```

What you're doing (`self`, `this`'s, and confusing arguments aside is):

```
callPolyfills([
    foo(),
    foo(),
    foo()
]);
```

... i.e. saying "hi" to `callPolyfills` numerous times, without actually passing it what you want.

What you should be passing is;

```
callPolyfills([
    foo,
    foo,
    foo
]);
```

This stops you being able to specify arguments to the functions though; in this circumstance the easiest way to do this would be to wrap those functions in anonymous functions.

```
this.callPolyfills([
  function () { 
    self.polyfillize([{
      test: [Modernizr.localstorage, Modernizr.sessionstorage],
      polyfill: [self.polyfills_url.storage_polyfill_url]
    }, {
      test: [Modernizr.json],
      polyfill: [self.polyfills_url.json_polyfill_url]
    }]);
  }, function () {
    self.prettifyCode(self.prettify, self.libraries_url.google_code_prettyfier.css, self.libraries_url.google_code_prettyfier.js);
  },
  self.consoleAvoidError
]);
```

... but then I'm not sure what you're gaining *really*.